# Keep JavaScript function after browser go back button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JavaScript `getElementById` function to show a picture on my page when the drop down value is selected. But after submit if I use the browser back button the picture is gone. I realize this is probably a Cache-Control issue. Is there anyway I can keep this function other than using Cache-control? I am committing lots of variables to session cookies and I'm afraid to mess around with cache-control.

```
function check_dd() {
    if(document.getElementById('show_pic').value == "") {
        document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'block';
    }
}

<select class="default" id="show_pic" onchange="check_dd();">
    <option value="" selected>Select question...</option>
    <option value="1">Question One</option>
    <option value="2">Question Two</option>
    <option value="3">Question Three</option>
    <option value="4">Question Four</option>
    <option value="5">Question Five</option>
    <option value="6">Question Six</option> 
</select>

<div id="test" style="display:none;"><img src="images/dcard.jpg" width="60" height="120" alt=""/></div>
```

How can I display the image after browser back button?

Comment: Would need to store page state in cookie or localStorage and shck when page loads

Answer (score 0):

My function was tied to the value of a select option which was already getting stored in the browser cache. So I found an easy way to fix this issue by just using:

```
<body onload="check_dd()">
```

This way I didn't have to add any extra code.